# Purpose of the "persist" partition

Tags: partitions

There are a lot of posts on the internet on how to fix or restore, but not many about what it is for or what is stored on it. What gets stored on it? Does the SIM unlock code go there? Or are values related to cellular functionality stored there (e.g., IMEI, CID, etc.)? In what way is it persistent?

Comment: Persist is partition mounted at /persist. It has ext4 file system. DRM releated files, sensor reg file (sns.reg), wifi and bluetooth mac addresses are stored there. -- edited by Moderator Firelord